# Filtro en incidencias de Jira

Tags: c#, jira

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para JIra y me gustaría filtrar todos los "issues" y no doy con la forma. De momento he puesto un rango de 350 para ir avanzando pero me gustaría que filtrase todos los "issues" independientemente de su número, porque en un futuro se podría dar el caso de que hubieran más de 350 issues abiertos.

Aqui les dejo mi código:

```
var issuesInFilter = jiraConnection.Filters.GetIssuesFromFilterAsync(filter.Id, 350).Result;
```

Toda recomendación es bienvenida :)

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Ahora mismo estoy filtrando por cantidad de registros (350) pero me gustaría filtrar por un rango que cogiera todos los registros, independientemente del número, no sé si hay alguna opción para ello.

Comment: La documentacion no lo aclara?

Answer (score -2):

Podrías utilizar la función Take para tomar un total de registros, o bien creo que con el uso de un índice como rango podría funcionar, siempre y cuando tengas los registros como un arreglo.

Comment: Hola Erik, te sugeriría que borres esta respuesta, en principio, fijate la fecha de la publicación, es difícil que obtengas feedback del OP, por otro lado, te sugiero pasar por [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada, y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!